# Why is nuclear waste, waste?

Tags: radioactivity

My colleagues and I are chatting and none of us know why nuclear waste is waste.

That is to say, if something is still radioactive, why can't that radiation be used? Can't the energy from, at least some of the more radioactive, "waste" products be used to, say, generate energy?

If the question itself doesn't give you any clues, let me say that I have **no** background in anything approaching a related topic.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201035/why-isnt-spent-nuclear-fuel-used-as-a-heat-source/201046#comment428277_201046

Comment: You can extract useful energy from anything that's warmer than it's surrouding environment, but that does not mean there's any commercial value in doing so.  Spent nuclear fuel is incredibly dangerous (i.e., very costly to move or handle or process).  And, within days of being removed from the reactor, it's power output will be down to a fraction of a percent of what the reactor produces while it is running.

Comment: The main problem with radioactive materials you can find in good quantity in nature that despite they have a high specific energy (TJ/kg magnitude) they have a low specific power. This correlates with long half life. For example from 1kg of SR-90 (~29 years half life) you can get around 1kW power. I think you can imagine how much power you could get from uranium (gigayear magnitude half life) without controlled fission. You could use the beta emitters in betavoltaic cells or do something like this: https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/850408 , but the specific power will be always low.